# Resetting JPanel in another class file

Tags: java, swing, oop, constructor, jpanel

I have a GUI created in my main class file

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTac extends JFrame {
TicTacEvent tictac = new TicTacEvent(this);
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JButton[][] boxes = new JButton[4][4];
JButton play = new JButton("Play");
JButton restart = new JButton("Restart");
JTextField blank1 = new JTextField();
JTextField blank2 = new JTextField();
JOptionPane win = new JOptionPane("Winner");
ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg");

public TicTac() {
    super ("Tic Tac Toe");
    setSize (800,650);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(layout);
    int name = 0;
    String newname;

    GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(5, 4, 10, 10);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            name = name + 1;
            newname = Integer.toString(name);
            boxes[x][y] = new JButton(newname);
            boxes[x][y].setIcon(back);
            row1.add(boxes[x][y]);
        }
    }
    row1.add(blank1);
    row1.add(play);
    row1.add(blank2);
    row1.add(restart);
    add (row1);

    play.addActionListener(tictac);
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
            boxes[x][y].addActionListener(tictac);
        }
    }


    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] arguments){
    TicTac frame = new TicTac();
}
}
```

And I have code using it here

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class TicTacEvent implements ItemListener, ActionListener, Runnable {

TicTac gui;
Thread playing;
Thread restarting;
ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("x.jpg");
ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("o.jpg");
int clicks = 0;
int win = 0;
int winx = 0;
int winy = 0;
int cat = 0;

int[][] check = new int[4][4];

public TicTacEvent (TicTac in){

    gui = in;
    for (int row=0; row<=3; row++){
    for (int col=0; col<=3; col++){
           check[row][col]=0;
       }
   }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

   String command = event.getActionCommand();

if (command.equals("Play")) {
startPlaying();
} else if (command.equals("Restart")) {
restart();
 }

   if (command.equals("1")) {
       b1();
   }
   if (command.equals("2")) {
       b2();
   }
   if (command.equals("3")) {
       b3();
   }
   if (command.equals("4")) {
       b4();
   }
   if (command.equals("5")) {
       b5();
   }
   if (command.equals("6")) {
       b6();
   }
   if (command.equals("7")) {
       b7();
   }
   if (command.equals("8")) {
       b8();
   }
   if (command.equals("9")) {
       b9();
   }
    if (command.equals("10")) {
       b10();
   }
    if (command.equals("11")) {
       b11();
   }
    if (command.equals("12")) {
       b12();
   }
    if (command.equals("13")) {
       b13();
   }
    if (command.equals("14")) {
       b14();
   }
   if (command.equals("15")) {
       b15();
   }
   if (command.equals("16")) {
       b16();
   }



    gui.blank1.setText("X Wins: " + winx + " Y Wins:" + winy);
    gui.blank2.setText("Cat Wins(Tie):" + cat);

}

void b1() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(a);
        check[0][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(b);
        check[0][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();

}
void b2() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(a);
        check[0][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(b);
        check[0][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b3() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(a);
        check[0][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(b);
        check[0][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b4() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[0][3].setIcon(a);
        check[0][3] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[0][3].setIcon(b);
        check[0][3] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b5() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(a);
        check[1][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(b);
        check[1][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b6() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(a);
        check[1][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(b);
        check[1][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b7() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(a);
        check[1][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(b);
        check[1][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b8() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[1][3].setIcon(a);
        check[1][3] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[1][3].setIcon(b);
        check[1][3] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
void b9() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(a);
        check[2][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(b);
        check[2][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
   void b10() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(a);
        check[2][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(b);
        check[2][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
          void b11() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(a);
        check[2][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(b);
        check[2][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
                 void b12() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[2][3].setIcon(a);
        check[2][3] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[2][3].setIcon(b);
        check[2][3] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
    void b13() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[3][0].setIcon(a);
        check[3][0] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[3][0].setIcon(b);
        check[3][0] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
   void b14() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[3][1].setIcon(a);
        check[3][1] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[3][1].setIcon(b);
        check[3][1] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
       void b15() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[3][2].setIcon(a);
        check[3][2] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[3][2].setIcon(b);
        check[3][2] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}
    void b16() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if ((clicks%2)==1){
        gui.boxes[3][3].setIcon(a);
        check[3][3] = 1;
    } else {
        gui.boxes[3][3].setIcon(b);
        check[3][3] = 2;
    }
    winner();
}

public void winner() {
    /** Check rows for winner */

    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        if ((check[x][0]==check[x][1])&&(check[x][0]==check[x][2]) && (check[x][0]== check[x][3])) {

            if (check[x][0] ==1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                win = 1;
                winx +=1;

            } else if (check[x][0]==2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y is the winner");
                win = 1;
                winy +=1;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Check columns for winner */
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
        if ((check[0][x]==check[1][x])&&(check[0][x]==check[2][x])&& (check[0][x]== check[3][x])) {
            if (check[0][x]==1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                win = 1;
                winx +=1;


            } else if (check[0][x]==2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y is the winner");
                win = 1;
                winy +=1;

            }
        }
    }
        if ((check[1][1]== 1) && (check[3][3] == 1) && (check[2][2]==1) && (check[0][0]==1)
            || (check[3][0]==1) &&(check[1][2]==1) &&(check[0][3]==1))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
            win = 1;
            winx +=1;

        } else if ((check[1][1]== 2) && (check[3][3] == 2) && (check[2][2]==2) &&         (check[0][0]==2)
            || (check[3][0]==2) &&(check[1][2]==2) &&(check[0][3]==2)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y is the winner");
            win = 1;
            winy +=1;

        }

    //}

    /** Checks if the game is a tie */
    if ((clicks==16) && (win==0)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game is a tie");
       cat =+1;

    }


}

public void startPlaying() {
    playing = new Thread(this);
    playing.start();
    gui.play.setEnabled(false);
}
public void restart() {
TicTac restartok = new TicTac();
restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank1);
restartok.row1.add(restartok.play);
restartok.row1.add(restartok.blank2);
restartok.row1.add(restartok.restart);
restartok.add (restartok.row1);

restartok.play.addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
        restartok.boxes[x][y].addActionListener(restartok.tictac);
    }
}
}


public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
 //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public void run() {
//restart();
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

}


}
```

However my question is how I'd reset the GUI, I have some ideas..

The constructor "Public TicTac" creates the gui, however I am not sure how I'd get to happen again through another classfile. My understanding of OOP is that with a constructor I can call to by creating an object

```
TicTac restartok = new TicTac();
```

So assumedly, you'd think I'd be creating another JPanel/GUI everytime I called the restart(); method, no?

My OOP expeirence is limited, so I don't have a clue where to start or find out what logic is incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: You are passing an TicTac object to TicTacEvent through constructor. I think, you can use the same object again by resetting in restart function. I'm not sure about this, for creating Events and EventListeners checking observer pattern will help you

Comment: If you create a GUI model, and separate it from your GUI view, then you can restart by re-initializing the model fields.  There's no need to recreate the view.  The pattern is called the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller).

Comment: @PramodPP could you clarify?

Comment: You need to create a function for resetting the UI in TicTac. Call it in cunstructor for first time initialization. and then in restart you can use gui.restart() and use the same gui for other actions too. If it is not clear please post the entire code I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the game, just reset `clicks` to 0 and the buttons to their original state just as they were created:

```
boxes[x][y] = new JButton(newname);
boxes[x][y].setIcon(back);
```

Apart from that, you have *many* things to fix in your code. Here are some:

- Your line `boxes[x][y].addActionListener(tictac);` is in a loop of its own where it should be in the initial loop. No reason to iterate twice over the same arrays.
- Your layout decisions could be better (depending on what *exactly* you want to get).
- Start the GUI with `TicTac frame = new TicTac();` from inside an `invokeLater` method.
- Create an `ActionListener` for each button with a unique functionality. In your case it's 1 for play, 1 for restart, and 1 for all the board buttons.
- You're using `event.getActionCommand` but you did not call `setActionCommand` on any of the buttons.
- Don't use multiple `if` when you check for the button pressed (action command name), use `if else`, or better - use a `switch` statement.
- Don't use a separate function for each button. Use 1 function which receives the button as its argument.
- Don't create fields when you can create local variables instead.

If you need clarifications leave a comment.

**Edit:** here is some modified code that resets the buttons (I couldn't stop myself from correcting other parts of the code, though there is still more to do).

```
public class TicTac extends JFrame {

    static JButton[][] boxes = new JButton[4][4];
    static int[][] check = new int[4][4];
    static JTextField blank1 = new JTextField();
    static JTextField blank2 = new JTextField();
    static int turns = 1;

    static ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg");
    static ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon("x.jpg");
    static ImageIcon o = new ImageIcon("o.jpg");

    public TicTac() {

        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 4, 10, 10));

        for (int x = 0; x<=3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y<=3; y++) {
                boxes[x][y] = new JButton(""+x+y, back);
                boxes[x][y].addActionListener(new XOActionListenr(x, y));
                gamePanel.add(boxes[x][y]);
            }
        }

        JButton play = new JButton("Play");
        JButton restart = new JButton("Restart");
        play.addActionListener(new PlayActionListenr());
        restart.addActionListener(new RestartActionListenr());

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        gamePanel.add(blank1);
        gamePanel.add(play);
        gamePanel.add(blank2);
        gamePanel.add(restart);
        add(gamePanel);

        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void winner() {

        // Check for winner
    }

    private class XOActionListenr implements ActionListener {

        private int row, col;

        private XOActionListenr(int row, int col) {

            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (turns % 2 == 0) {
                boxes[row][col].setText("O");
                boxes[row][col].setIcon(o);
                check[row][col] = 2;
            }
            else {
                boxes[row][col].setText("X");
                boxes[row][col].setIcon(x);
                check[row][col] = 1;
            }
            winner();
            turns++;
        }
    }

    private class PlayActionListenr implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Not sure why you would need the "play" button at all,
            // but insert here what it's supposed to do
        }
    }

    private class RestartActionListenr implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            for (int x = 0; x<=3; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y<=3; y++) {
                    boxes[x][y].setText(""+x+y);
                    boxes[x][y].setIcon(back);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                new TicTac();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @user18035551 Thanks for putting effort into your comment. I've tried that in my restart(); method already 
     `clicks =0;
    int name = 0;
    String newname;
    for (int x=0; x<=3; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<=3; y++){
    name = name + 1;
    newname = Integer.toString(name);
    gui.boxes[x][y] = new JButton(newname);
    gui.boxes[x][y].setIcon(back);
    gui.row1.add(gui.boxes[x][y]);'`

However it is not going through, I added ` else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown command: "+ command);
}'` to check if it wasn't going through but it seems to be.

Comment: And thanks, I'll slowly try to fix what you said to, ironically this is my teachers code, not mine, my assignment was to add win/loss counter, and size of board. Kinda stuck with Catch 22, can't learn more because haven't handed this in to see future lessons, haha.

Comment: @Alivesi If the code in the post is your teacher's code stop taking the class immediately and file a complaint for incompetence (not joking). As for the code, you don't needs to add the buttons again, just set the text and image of the existing ones.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to continue asking for more clarification, sorry. I'm not sure I get what you are trying to explain. Set the text? Excluding that, I tried setting the image of the existing through the loop and [x][y].setIcon(back); and it still won't set any images, which is weird because it works in my earlier code. I've never felt this ignorant coding before. @user1803551

Comment: @Alivesi Don't be shy to ask for help after you tried your best. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to re-create whole GUI again and again. what you need to do is to clear textfields and whatever selection user has made till now. So you need to create a separate method in which you will reset the state of every button/textfields in your GUI.

for example: to clear `textfield` you will call `setText("")` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the buttons, they are set to a picture, would this still work? I'l ltry

Comment: Yes you can reset the pictures on your buttons as well